# Get Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package when deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

```
sdilshod@sdilshod-Lenovo-B590:~/webapp/saturn$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6194
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in    vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0.  Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app  as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release  notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2- 0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in  vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0.   Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app   as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release   notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-  0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
 Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.
 rake aborted!
 Error dumping database
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-   3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:415:in `block (3 levels)   in <top (required)>'
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord- 3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:188:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:182:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

heroku pg:psql works fine, but when i do migrate rake db:migrate it get error that needs to install pg client. Where i need to install pg client? Any help

Comment: I found [this][1] solution and fix error


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300341/migrate-not-working-on-heroku

Answer (score 351):

On a Debian based system the PostreSQL client programs are provided by **postgresql-client-common** as symbolic links to `/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper`.

If you install that package and attempt to use any of the PostgreSQL client programs like **psql**, **pg_dump**, **pg_dumpall**, and **pg_restore**, the **pg_wrapper** without having the version specific binary package installed, like **postgresql-client-9.1** it will emit this error:

> You must install at least one postgresql-client-< version > package

The easiest way to fix this is to install the **postgresql-client** metapackage. It always depends on the currently supported database client package for PostgreSQL on Debian based systems and it depends on postgresql-client-common

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

Comment: Thanks for response, jla! It seems bug heroku and i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300341/migrate-not-working-on-heroku  to solve

Comment: You're welcome. I found this when searching for the "at least one" error message from using psql on the command line and not using heroku. After I found the answer I wanted to leave a Debian specific fix that gives a working pg_dump and psql for the Debian specific error as an alternate to the suggested heroku fix of ignoring the error.

Comment: running `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client` via `heroku run bash` doesn't work? It returns `bash: sudo: command not found`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Running this command `sudo apt install postgresql-client-common`

Answer (score 35):

**Update March 30th, 2020**

Agree with the chosen answer, but I found to install **postgresql-client-12** on a Ubuntu 18 slightly more involved.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install vim bash-completion wget
sudo apt -y upgrade
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install postgresql-client-12
```

See [this reference](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-12-on-ubuntu/) for details.

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04 just the last line of the instructions did the trick.

Comment: For PostgreSQL 13, see their (almost identical) guide here: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 18):

For Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS it works with only two commands;

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

Answer (score 1):

with new version postgresql 14, I follow up this document

http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/README

```
$ sudo su - 

$ lsb_release -c

Codename:       focal

$ echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

$ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-14
```