# Database Migrations on Secondary Database on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, rake

Our company acquired an application from another company, so I'm a little unfamiliar with how they may have done this in the past.  Currently there are two applications in Heroku.  A production and staging app.  Below is the basic app  setup for clarity.

```
Production App
   WHITE // Primary database
   BLACK // Secondary database linked to Staging App

Staging App
   // No databases
```

Staging application has Config Vars that point to `BLACK` database URL.

I am trying to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` on our staging app, but noticed the database is linked to a secondary production `BLACK` database.

If I run

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate -a production
```

It will update the primary `WHITE` database in production, but I want to test on the secondary `BLACK` database first.

If I run

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate -a staging
```

I get the following error

```
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database
...
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I target the secondary `BLACK` database with a rake command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Heroku support, I was not able to get this to work with the current configuration.  So in the end I decided to create a database for our staging app.  Imported the latest dump file from production. And ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` against staging.

I still got the same error from my original post (see original question).  But when I checked the staging database, the schema was updated correctly.  Heroku pointed me to the following [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306077/63308), which seems to indicate this may be a Rails 3 bug.

Below solution for clarity:

```
Production App
  WHITE // Primary database
  BLACK // Deleted

Staging App
  Gray // Primary database
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gemfile to make sure your database driver psql isn't in a production only block.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I checked the Gemfile and confirmed that pg is not in a production only block.  I have created a ticket for Heroku  support too as I am stumped.